# submit handler not working in custom.module?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have a submit handler for a form im tryin to submit into webform submissions. i have the handler like this:

```
function custom_webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.components');
global $user;

$node = $form['#node'];
$sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'] ? (int) $form_state['values']['details']  ['sid'] : NULL;

if (!$sid) {
  // Create a new submission object.
  $submission = (object) array(
    'nid' => $node->nid, 
    'uid' => $form_state['values']['details']['uid'], 
    'submitted' => REQUEST_TIME, 
    'remote_addr' => ip_address(), 
    'is_draft' => $is_draft, 
    'data' => webform_submission_data($node, $form_state['values']['submitted']),
  );
}
else {
  // To maintain time and user information, load the existing submission.
  $submission = webform_get_submission($node->webform['nid'], $sid);
  $submission->is_draft = $is_draft;

  // Merge with new submission data. The + operator maintains numeric keys.
  // This maintains existing data with just-submitted data when a user resumes
  // a submission previously saved as a draft.
  $new_data = webform_submission_data($node, $form_state['values']['submitted']);
  $submission->data = $new_data + $submission->data;
}

// If there is no data to be saved (such as on a multipage form with no fields
// on the first page), process no further. Submissions with no data cannot
// be loaded from the database as efficiently, so we don't save them at all.
if (empty($submission->data)) {
  return;
}

// Save the submission to the database.
if (!$sid) {
  // No sid was found thus insert it in the dataabase.
  $form_state['values']['details']['sid'] = $sid = webform_submission_insert($node,  $submission);
  $form_state['values']['details']['is_new'] = TRUE;

 drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

The part that seems to throw an error for me is  the following one.

```
if (!$sid) {
  // Create a new submission object.
  $submission = (object) array(
    'nid' => $node->nid, 
    'uid' => $form_state['values']['details']['uid'], 
    'submitted' => REQUEST_TIME, 
    'remote_addr' => ip_address(), 
    'is_draft' => $is_draft, 
    'data' => webform_submission_data($node, $form_state['values']['submitted']),
  );
}
```

When I comment out these lines, the form just returns empty values.

Why is it not able to create a submission object, and what is giving me errors?

Comment: Also post your form_alter part that adds this new submit handler.

Comment: its not a form_alter its a hook_form custom form '$form['submit'] = array( // Submit button
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#submit' => array('contracts_webform_submit'),
 );
 return $form;
}'

Comment: Why use webforms from code, when you can use the form api directly?

Comment: i dont want to create a new database for my submission i want to submit it as  a webform cuz its only one form of basic fields and fieldsets but its over 50 fields(3 forms in 1 themed) and i didnt have time or know_how to create a 50 webform then Form_alter theme of the fields. so i created the form using FORM API and now im tryin to submit it as a webform submission object or node object.